# Finder applescript: Odd behaviour

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, finder

I'm on OSX Snow Leopard (I had the same issue on Leopard, though..)
This is the applescript:

```
tell application "Finder" to set my_from to selection
tell application "Finder" to set my_to to target of window 2
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 31)
tell application "Finder" to move my_from to my_to
```

It moves the current selection to the second Finder window, but before actually moving it advances to the next file by pressing arrow down (I'm in list view), so that I don't lose my position everytime I move something.

Problem is: it works every other time! You actually have to execute it twice to make it work!!

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I got this: `error "Finder got an error: Can’t get alias file \"\"." number -1728 from alias file ""`. ??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

as the first line.

Answer (score 0):

My only testing was saving it as an app and launching it from the Dock, but by merely incorporating Paul's activate suggestion (and blocking them all into one tell for fun), I could not get this code to fail or require two clicks:

```
tell application "Finder"
   activate
   set my_from to selection
   set my_to to target of window 2
   tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 31)
   move my_from to my_to
end tell
```

Comment: If you say so, I'll have to investigate on the real cause.. If I remove the keystroke, everything's fine. So it must be connected to that somehow..